# Run code when `Animated.timing()` in `Animated.sequence()` completes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, animation

I am building a dynamic animation based on user input, I read the input and create corresponding `Animated.timing()` objects that I then pass into `Animated.sequence`, which I set to loop. Simplified code would look like this:

```js
let animations = [];

for ( /* read user input, use it to define params of the animation parts */ ) {

  let inhaleAnim = Animated.timing(scaleValue, {/*params*/});
  let hold1Anim = Animated.timing(scaleValue, {/*params*/});
  let exhaleAnim = Animated.timing(scaleValue, {/*params*/});
  let hold2Anim = Animated.timing(scaleValue, {/*params*/});

  animations.push(inhaleAnim, hold1Anim, exhaleAnim, hold2Anim);
}

const animate = (sequence) => {
  // Starts the sequence and ensures it will be looping.
  Animated.sequence(sequence).start( () => { animate(sequence); } );
}

animate(animations);
```

I need to be able to run code after each "finish" of the `Animated.timing()` that work together to comprise the animation sequence. In more human words, everytime animation of inhaling completes, a sound is player. Everytime animation for holding breath completes, a sound is played and so on.

I read through the documentation and initially thought I might be able to simply define callback for completion for each of the timings, but when I tested this, I realized that when I call `.start()` on a timing to be able to provide callback, I end up inadvertly starting the timing animation immediatelly, doesn't do what I want.

How?